# unterminated string literal on json eval

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, eval

I am trying to eval() a json having speacial characters - â€¨
and getting "unterminated string literal" error in Firefox 3.5.9
Although the same works fine on IE. 7.
I have set the character encoding to UTF-8 in both the browsers.
Any idea why its an error in FF?

Also right before converting the String to JSON, I ran this code in java

```
String jsonString = //some json string having â€¨
for(byte b : jsonString.getBytes()){
    System.out.print(Integer.toHexString(b) + " ");
}
net.sf.json.JSON jsonObject = net.sf.json.JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonString);
```

And the o/p for above characters is

ffffffe2 ffffff80 ffffffa8 respectively.
How do I know if these are valid UTF-8 characters?

Comment: The exact JSON string that results in the error would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Tried using gson API for java-to-json. And works fine.
Posting both the resulting jsons.

**Resulting JSON using json-lib (gives unterminated string literal error)**

```
 var json = {"addToSessionFlag":false,"addToShoppingCart":false,"allMessageCodes":"IXMANAGER__PARSING_STATUS#","beanKey":"","cacheFlag":false,"callBackData":{"IXMANAGER_PARSER_ERROR_LIST":[{**"cellData":"â€¨34295"**,"columnHeader":"","columnNumber":8,"errorMessage":"Error : Invalid Zip Code","rowNumber":1},{"cellData":"","columnHeader":"","columnNumber":9,"errorMessage":"Error : Invalid Contact Person","rowNumber":1},{"cellData":"+90-(0)212-4113838â€¨","columnHeader":"","columnNumber":10,"errorMessage":"Error : Invalid Phone Numbers","rowNumber":1},{"cellData":"adnan.harunoglu@gdc.travel","columnHeader":"","columnNumber":12,"errorMessage":"Error : Invalid Email Address","rowNumber":1},{"cellData":"41.000792,28.802633","columnHeader":"","columnNumber":14,"errorMessage":"Error : Invalid Website","rowNumber":1},{"cellData":"15:00 p.m","columnHeader":"","columnNumber":19,"errorMessage":"Error : Invalid Hotel Check-In/Check-Out Time","rowNumber":1},{"cellData":"12:00 p.m","columnHeader":"","columnNumber":20,"errorMessage":"Error : Invalid Hotel Check-In/Check-Out Time","rowNumber":1}]}};

var test = eval(json); 
alert(test);
```

**Resulting JSON using gson (succesful eval. works!)**

```
 var json = {"keyId":0,"sSuccessType":"||ERR||","sSuccessMessage":"Parsing Failed\u003cBR /\u003e","_bAddToSessionFlag":false,"bCacheFlag":false,"success":false,"callBackData":{"IXMANAGER_PARSER_ERROR_LIST":[{"_iRowNumber":1,"_iColumnNumber":8,**"_sCellData":"\u202834295"**,"_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Zip Code"},{"_iRowNumber":1,"_iColumnNumber":9,"_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Contact Person"},{"_iRowNumber":2,"_iColumnNumber":9,"_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Contact Person"},{"_iRowNumber":1,"_iColumnNumber":10,"_sCellData":"+90-(0)212-4113838\u2028","_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Phone Numbers"},{"_iRowNumber":1,"_iColumnNumber":12,"_sCellData":"adnan.harunoglu@gdc.travel","_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Email Address"},{"_iRowNumber":2,"_iColumnNumber":12,"_sCellData":"adnan.harunoglu@gdc.travel","_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Email Address"},{"_iRowNumber":1,"_iColumnNumber":14,"_sCellData":"41.000792,28.802633","_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Website"},{"_iRowNumber":2,"_iColumnNumber":14,"_sCellData":"40.971911,28.871362","_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Website"},{"_iRowNumber":1,"_iColumnNumber":19,"_sCellData":"15:00 p.m","_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Hotel Check-In/Check-Out Time"},{"_iRowNumber":2,"_iColumnNumber":19,"_sCellData":"14:00 p.m","_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Hotel Check-In/Check-Out Time"},{"_iRowNumber":1,"_iColumnNumber":20,"_sCellData":"12:00 p.m","_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Hotel Check-In/Check-Out Time"},{"_iRowNumber":2,"_iColumnNumber":20,"_sCellData":"12:00 p.m","_sErrorMessage":"Error : Invalid Hotel Check-In/Check-Out Time"}]}};
 var test = eval(json); 
alert(test);
```

Although this is not the complete solution to my problem as I think gson uses class variables directly instead of getters at the time of json serialization.
Any thoughts about it?

Comment: Looks like your original string isn't JSON.  Any non-ASCII safe character in JSON needs to be encoded using its unicode escape sequence (\uXXXX).  The first string does not have this correctly encoded, so it's a problem with your encoder.